# How to resolve the following apache pig error?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am executing the following commands:

```
A= load 'user/cloudera' using PigStorage(':');
foreach A generate $0,$4,$5;
dump B;
```

On executing the last command I get the following error which I am unable to resolve.Being a newbie to bigdata and apache hadoop stack,I am unable to comprehend this error.Please help ASAP.Also searching on StackOverflow for similar errors did not help:

```
2015-11-13 06:36:46,170 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: UNKNOWN
2015-11-13 06:36:46,208 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer - {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, DuplicateForEachColumnRewrite, GroupByConstParallelSetter, ImplicitSplitInserter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter, MergeFilter, MergeForEach, NewPartitionFilterOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter, SplitFilter, StreamTypeCastInserter], RULES_DISABLED=[FilterLogicExpressionSimplifier, PartitionFilterOptimizer]}
2015-11-13 06:36:46,212 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2015-11-13 06:36:46,225 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 1
2015-11-13 06:36:46,225 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 1
2015-11-13 06:36:46,404 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2015-11-13 06:36:46,415 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
2015-11-13 06:36:46,445 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2015-11-13 06:36:49,232 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - creating jar file Job306801006066349255.jar
2015-11-13 06:37:04,185 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - jar file Job306801006066349255.jar created
2015-11-13 06:37:04,223 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting up single store job
2015-11-13 06:37:04,238 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Key [pig.schematuple] is false, will not generate code.
2015-11-13 06:37:04,238 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Starting process to move generated code to distributed cache
2015-11-13 06:37:04,238 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Setting key [pig.schematuple.classes] with classes to deserialize []
2015-11-13 06:37:04,274 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
2015-11-13 06:37:04,274 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2015-11-13 06:37:04,283 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2015-11-13 06:37:04,363 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-11-13 06:37:05,416 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - Cleaning up the staging area /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/cloudera/.staging/job_1447417089361_0004
2015-11-13 06:37:05,420 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation - PriviledgedActionException as:cloudera (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/user/cloudera
2015-11-13 06:37:05,420 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob - PigLatin:DefaultJobName got an error while submitting 
org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/user/cloudera
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1303)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.submit(PigJobControl.java:128)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:270)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/user/cloudera
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:321)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:264)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigTextInputFormat.listStatus(PigTextInputFormat.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:385)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:274)
    ... 18 more
2015-11-13 06:37:05,423 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - HadoopJobId: job_1447417089361_0004
2015-11-13 06:37:05,423 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Processing aliases A,B
2015-11-13 06:37:05,423 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - detailed locations: M: A[3,3],B[4,3] C:  R: 
2015-11-13 06:37:05,423 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - More information at: http://localhost:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_1447417089361_0004
2015-11-13 06:37:05,440 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
2015-11-13 06:37:10,463 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure.
2015-11-13 06:37:10,463 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job job_1447417089361_0004 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2015-11-13 06:37:10,463 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2015-11-13 06:37:10,620 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Could not get Job info from RM for job job_1447417089361_0004. Redirecting to job history server.
2015-11-13 06:37:10,844 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Could not get Job info from RM for job job_1447417089361_0004. Redirecting to job history server.
2015-11-13 06:37:10,849 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2015-11-13 06:37:10,850 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics: 

HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
2.6.0-cdh5.4.2  0.12.0-cdh5.4.2 cloudera    2015-11-13 06:36:46 2015-11-13 06:37:10 UNKNOWN

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_1447417089361_0004  A,B MAP_ONLY    Message: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/user/cloudera
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1303)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.submit(PigJobControl.java:128)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:270)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/user/cloudera
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:321)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:264)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigTextInputFormat.listStatus(PigTextInputFormat.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:385)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:274)
    ... 18 more
    hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/tmp/temp-193566860/tmp-1023933528,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/user/cloudera"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/tmp/temp-193566860/tmp-1023933528"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_1447417089361_0004


2015-11-13 06:37:10,850 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2015-11-13 06:37:10,853 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias B
Details at logfile: /home/cloudera/pig_1447424730804.log
```

Comment: What's your input path? Which file contains your input?

Comment: input path?what do u mean by that?

Comment: In your script, you are using "user/cloudera" as input path, which seems incorrect.

Comment: For people who found this post when looking for [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:**

Change line 1 of your code to:

```
A= load '/user/cloudera' using PigStorage(':');
```

Having said that, are you sure your input data is in your home area? That seems unlikely. It's more likely to be in a folder within your home area, i.e. `/user/cloudera/input-data`.

Before running your job do:

```
hdfs dfs -ls /user/cloudera
```

to confirm that input data is actually in that folder. If it's not, work out where it actually is, and make sure it is on the HDFS and not locally.

**Explanation:**

The relevant part of the logs is

```
ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/user/cloudera
```

This suggests it's related to the input path. The part of your code that deals with the input path is

```
A= load 'user/cloudera' using PigStorage(':');
```

By not adding a forward slash to `/user` then it assumes that everything is relative to your home area, so for example writing `load 'input'` would   lead the Pig job to read in `hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8028/user/cloudera/input`. In your case then the missing slash means it adds it to your user area.

Answer (score 1):

Please check where are you running pig statements in local/linux mode or mapreduce mode , if you are running local mode you cant read HDFS file

run this cmd $ pig -x mapreduce

after this 
Grunt> A = load '/;
Grunt>Dump/store /

Answer (score 0):

Input(s):

```
Failed to read data from 

"hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/user/cloudera"
```

Output(s):

```
Failed to produce result in "hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/tmp/temp-193566860/tmp-1023933528"
```

Counters:

```
Total records written : 0

Total bytes written : 0

Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0

Total bags proactively spilled: 0

Total records proactively spilled: 0
```

If you look at the above error code (copied from question that was posted), input file path is taken by pig as below

**'hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/user/cloudera'**

So when running pig in mapreduce mode and using quickstart VM, you have use

'hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020' before your input file path....

Is the input a folder?...if so pig script will read all the files in the folder....

Example:

say your input file path which is located in hdfs is  **'/usr/cloudera/inputdata.txt'** then your query has to be

A= load 'hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/inputdata.txt' using PigStorage(':');

foreach A generate $0,$4,$5;

dump B;

Answer (score -1):

The only thing that u have to check is the file path.

1. hdfs dfs -ls /
   check how the path structure comes.
   like ..../input/data/file.
   file u are going to use.
2. A = load '/input/data/file';
3. dump A;

only thing is the proper path of your file that u want to load.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue and I was able to fix by deleting the `passwd` file from the target folder and then copying it again using the correct relative path:

```
A= load '/user/cloudera' using PigStorage(':');
```

The instruction in the video is missing the '/' before the user

- Step 1:

  ```
  hdfs dfs -rm /user/cloudera/passwd
  ```
- Step 2:

  ```
  A= load '/user/cloudera' using PigStorage(':');
  ```

Then followed the instructions from the Coursera video.